# Sort array via item's sub-strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

My array contains items set out like:

> "item_name_1::item_description::item_value"

(so each item in the array contains separate pieces of data which is later split at "::")

and my question is, how can i sort the array by the "ITEM_VALUE" (which is a numeric value), i have tried the following, with no luck:

```
Arrays.sort(inputArr, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String entry1, String entry2) {
        String[] entry1Split = entry1.split("::");
        String[] entry2Split = entry2.split("::");

        return entry1Split[2].compareTo(entry2Split[2]);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've posted? It seems to be OK.

Comment: From perfromance perspective it worst splitting item each time you are doing comparision, split original array items in temporary arrays and then do sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
Arrays.sort(inputArr, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String entry1, String entry2) {
        String[] entry1Split = entry1.split("::");
        String[] entry2Split = entry2.split("::");

        return Double.valueOf(entry1Split[2]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(entry2Split[2]));
    }
});
```

that is, if your numerical values are floating point values.  If they are integer, you can use `Integer.valueOf` instead of `Double.valueOf`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to think about parsing the strings in the array and creating an object for each entry - something like

```
class Item {

    String value;
    String description
    Integer value;
}
```

that way you'll only parse the string once per object and not multiple times each time the sort algorithm needs to to do a compare.

Comment: While a useful comment in itself, it does not answer his question, therefore it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There's no way to post multiline answers and sample codes in the comment.

Comment: The downside of a real time dynamic system - Aleks G answered the question whilst I was part way through typing my answer. There didn't seem to be any point in repeating the answer so I edited the repeated stuff and was left with what should arguably have been a comment.